# Put an if statement inside a body vs. Duplicating the loop body

Tags: javascript

Right now I have a function with a loop:

```
      var formatColumnNames = function (col) {
          return _.map(col, function (column) {
              column.name = column.Display;
              column.field = column.Display;
              return column;
          });
      };
```

I want to add another parameter: sortable that is a boolean.

If sortable is true, then assign column.sortable = true inside the loop.

It looks ugly for me include this inside the loop (Loops O(n) times).

And I was thinking about doing an if statement before the loop, but that could mean repeating the loop I have in 2 places since I would have 2 different methods.

What is the cleanest way to do this?

Edit: I thought it's ugly because something like:

```
     var formatColumnNames = function (col, sortable) {
          if (sortable) {
          return _.map(col, function (column) {
              column.name = column.Display;
              column.field = column.Display;
              column.sortable = true;
              return column;
              });
          };
          else {
          return _.map(col, function (column) {
              column.name = column.Display;
              column.field = column.Display;
              return column;
              });
          }
```

Is a lot of duplication.

Comment: What's ugly about it?

Comment: @LucasRoss The second form is ugly (as per my view) because it represents duplication and a bad thing about duplication is it is *super easy* to introduce a bug during changes, such as adding a new column in the above. What if it was done to only one body?

Comment: [Re: your edit] The second parameter to _.map is a function. It can do the check itself and no duplication of code is needed. Example: `if (sortable) { column.sortable = sortable; }` right before `return column;`

Answer (score 1):

The loop doesn't go away - O(n) is still O(n) for an inconsequential change in C<sup>1</sup>. There is *no* problem* here; use the code that is most maintainable/preferable.

My preference is to *not* duplicate the loop body as, well, it represents duplication - it is harder for me to read and makes maintenance and modification of the code more error prone as any changes must also be duplicated.

If computing the expression is costly then it should be done outside the loop; however, this cannot be done inside the loop if it depends upon the item.

If doing the action is costly (and the expression is cheap as per above logic) then it doesn't matter where the action inside the conditional is done.

---

<sup>1</sup> The amount of "time" JavaScript uses to evaluate a trivial conditional/expression (eg. `if (x)`) should generally be considered inconsequential. If there *is* a problem it should first be identified with a performance benchmark. Even branch prediction (which is quite silly to apply to this level of JavaScript) doesn't apply because `x` is a constant for the execution of the code.